# Globally transform ngResource query()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, ngresource

I would like to transform the query() response of Angular's ngResource. No problem doing it by overriding the method in each factory/resource but how can I do it so that my transform applies to all query() methods across all resources?

I have tried using `$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse` but I see no way to differentiate between a query() call and all the other ones.

I am wanting to return pagination metadata - perhaps there is another way that might be clearner?

Comment: Oh geez... a typo :) ngResource!

Comment: Can you attach some code, showing the desired transformation.

Comment: Well it's not so much any particular transformation its' more a question of how can I tell the difference between all the queries that run through the global transformResponse - I am currently setting headers and checking these to see if they match but it's so lame that I went back to modifying each individual resource factory

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the endpoint, you could add an `X-Total-Count` header (https://github.com/drahak/Restful#paginator).  Your `$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse` can then detect the presence of the header to parse paging information.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.push( function( data, headersGetter ) {
  if( headersGetter('X-Total-Count') ) {
    // CUSTOM PAGING PROCESSING HERE
    console.info('Results Count', headersGetter('X-Total-Count'));
  }

  return data;
});
```